# Why do gvfs shares appear read only when accessed via CLI (command line)?

Tags: command-line, mount, sftp, gvfs, sshfs

please try it out yourself:

Mount a network share via "file"-"connect to server" in nemo filebrowser (this is a real pain when you try it via nautilus since gnome version 3, but that is another question).

Create a new file or modify a file via nemo or nautilus file browser: this works normally.

Then try to do this via the commandline:

```
touch /run/user/`id -u`/gvfs/sftp\:host=myserver.mydomain.be/tmp/test
```

You should get an error like this:

```
touch: setting times of '/run/user/`id -u`/gvfs/sftp\:host=myserver.mydomain.be/tmp/test': Operation not supported
```

Try the same with sshfs and it works.

Is this by design? A design flaw? Is there a workaround,... besides using sshfs?

Comment: They don't appear readonly. I get the error too, sure, but the file is created just fine. It's probably just that GVFS doesn't, as the error mentions, support setting  [modification/change/access] times.

Comment: even vim works, I had other strange errors. (with symbolic links and nfs mounts on the remote server accessed trough gvfs) but can't get them back right now, maybe I should investigate more and then rephrase my question